# How Can I Hide All Toolbars When Firefox is in Fullscreen?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

I want to use firefox as a front-end for users to see only one website.

I found how to start firefox in fullscreen, toolbars are hiding by default, but I cannot make the toolbars (address bar, tabbars etc) not showing up when the user hovers on the top of the screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think what you want is called kiosk mode ...

Comment: [Fullscreen Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen_plus/?src=search) is a more recent addon that accomplishes this in Firefox Quantum!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As lexu mentioned, what you want is typically called "kiosk mode".  To my knowledge, Firefox does not include built-in kiosk mode functionality (I think only IE includes it in the base version), but it is available with a couple of different Firefox plugins.

[R-Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/?src=search) is perhaps the most popular one.  I've used it before in one of my previous jobs with a Firefox 3.x setup, but I haven't tried it in a couple of years so I don't know about compatibility and functionality with newer browsers.  It does state it works through the latest versions of Firefox.

The other fairly popular one is [FF Fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/FF_Fullscreen/?src=search) which I haven't tried, but doesn't appear to be a full kiosk mode that prevents users from getting to the desktop, but rather just a fullscreen with no toolbars mode, which might be what you're looking for anyway.  Your question didn't state whether or not you wanted to keep users from getting to the desktop.

Comment: Both of these extensions are not compatible with Firefox 57+.

Comment: Not surprising for a 6 year old answer but good to know. The latest versions of Firefox broke a great many older plugins and features it appears.

Answer (score 9):

Got to about:config , search for [`browser.fullscreen.autohide`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.fullscreen.autohide) and change the value to true.

> ## Possible values and their effects
>
> ### True
>
> Automatically collapse toolbars and the tab strip in fullscreen mode and only show on mouseover. (Default)
>
> ### False
>
> Always show the toolbars and tab strip in fullscreen mode.

Comment: As you noted yourself, it is already true by default, so it is rather pointless.

Comment: It is no longer `true` by default. This is the solution in the 2021 version of Firefox

Comment: that's the only answer which worked for my Firefox in early 2022

Comment: False in FF 121.0 (64-bit), December 2023. Enabling it works as expected for my use case (just want zero clutter in full screen mode), thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can advantage of HTML5 Full Screen API.

Paste code below into console and click big black box to activate fullscreen mode:

```js
(function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div'),
      docEl = document.documentElement;

  el.innerText = 'Go to fullscreen view';
  el.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; padding: 30%; background: #000; color: #fff; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;')
  document.body.appendChild(el)

  el.onclick = function() {
    if (docEl.requestFullscreen) {
      docEl.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (docEl.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      docEl.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  };
})();
```

...or use bookmarklet:

```js
javascript:(function(){var e=document.createElement("div"),t=document.documentElement;e.innerText="Go to fullscreen view";e.setAttribute("style","position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; padding: 30%; background: #000; color: #fff; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;");document.body.appendChild(e);e.onclick=function(){if(t.requestFullscreen){t.requestFullscreen()}else if(t.mozRequestFullScreen){t.mozRequestFullScreen()}else if(t.webkitRequestFullscreen){t.webkitRequestFullscreen()}document.body.removeChild(e)}})();
```

Comment: You forgot to actually call the `requestFullscreen` function. :p

Comment: Bookmarklet - open in a browser and drag to bookmarks bar `<a href="javascript:(function(){var e=document.createElement('div'),t=document.documentElement;e.innerText='Go to fullscreen view';e.setAttribute('style','position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; padding: 30%; background: #000; color: #fff; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;');document.body.appendChild(e);e.onclick=function(){if(t.requestFullscreen){t.requestFullscreen()}else if(t.mozRequestFullScreen){t.mozRequestFullScreen()}else if(t.webkitRequestFullscreen){t.webkitRequestFullscreen()}document.body.removeChild(e)}})();">Fullscreen</a>
`

Answer (score 4):

On new Firefox v.71 currently on Nightly (Beta) you can add `--kiosk` when running to avoid all bars (navigation and tabs)

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is the 'Old Lion Fullscreen' addon. If works reliably (unlike FF Fullscreen which seems to have unpredictable full-screen behavior). The only drawback is that the menubar does not appear when hovering near the top.

Link : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/old-lion-fullscreen/

Comment: not compatible with Firefox 57+.

Answer (score 2):

1. Drag everything from the bars to the window opened by Right Click > Customize.
2. Go to Options > Tabs and disable Always Show Tab Bar.
3. Right Click and disable all four bars.
4. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> for full-screen mode, it should be kiosk-like if you only have one tab open.

This, however does not disallow the user from using shortcut keys to open new pages / tabs / windows.

Even when using an add-on or extension, **it does not disallow the user to mess with the system**. This is simply because Firefox doesn't seem to provide the mechanics to allow for a fully implemented kiosk mode, and since they haven't implemented it themselves someone has to take the source and write a kiosk mode himself.

---

You might want to try an alternative browser like [Opera's Kiosk Mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/), also look into the Group Policy of Windows to block additional shortcut keys like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and other user functionality...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
javascript:(document.onclick=()=>document.documentElement.requestFullscreen())();
```

This code is nice, because

1) It uses the modern `requestFullscreen` API.

2) Some browsers, Firefox for example, prevent full screen request without a user action. This code will enter fullscreen when the user clicks on any part of the page.

Comment: Please add more explanation on how to implement your code/command and what exactly it's suppose to do.

Answer (score 1):

Way 1:

Firefox's built-in "hide toolbar" option can be used as seen below image.

[image]

Way 2:

[Modern Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modern-kiosk/) doesn't work like a char yet does fill the bill. On your current tab, set current url as kiosk then enter kiosk mode.

[image]